# What's a clean way to manage state in Angular and have components update?

Tags: state, angular2

I'm using a service to manage state in Angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DrawingAreaService {
  itemChange: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  private foo = 'foo';

  get bar() {
    return this.foo;
  }

  set bar(value) {
    this.foo = value;
    this.itemChange.next(value);
  }
}
```

And in my component I have

```
get bar() {
  return this.service.bar;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.bar = 'test value';
}
```

html:

```
{{ this.bar }}
```

Calling the service and updating `bar` value on init does not trigger the component changes. If instead I also set to a field on the component, something like:

```
this.service.bar = 'test value';
this.bar = 'test value';
```

it triggers the change detection.

I'm wondering what's the best way to handle state changes like this, should I set on the service only and then call `detectChanges()`? Should I subscribe and set a class field from the subscription? Should I set twice?

Is there any other way to do this? How can I do it in a really simple way?

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't give much insight into what problem you're trying to solve so it's hard to give more practical direction, however I'd suggest using observables in this instance and potentially get rid of the property.

Something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class DrawingAreaService {
  itemChange: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject();

  private foo = 'foo';

  get bar$() {
    return this.foo;
  }

  updateBar() {
    this.itemChange.next(value);
  }
}
```

Then your component can simply be:

```
bar: string = '';

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.bar$.subscribe(bar => this.bar = bar);
}
```

As an alternative, you can ignore the above component code and use the observable directly in your template:

```
<div>{{service.bar$ | async}}</div>
```

Depending on your use-case, a `BehaviorSubject` might be a good move since you can use it directly to access the last value.

Comment: With subscribe in the component it would be a bit weird, because I would subscribe and change the value right away (like in the next line). Using directly the observable I would need to make the service public and use `async` pipe. I don't know exactly what I'm looking for, but thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to do this? How can I do it in a really simple way?

In my opinion (and my little experience), I find the given solution to be a walkaround rather than a solid solution. It's practical, but I doubt it's convenient. For several reasons.

One involves Angular's life cycle. When Angular re-evaluates the view has to solve first the state of the service. If the service is not holding the state locally and in memory (say it sends requests) that is translated into a high load for the remote end. Even if it doesn't send a request, if it has to perform some heavy task, it's taxing the Event Loop.

Another involves mutability. If `foo` was an object then the setter is only cosmetic. It doesn't make much sense since the getter is returning a reference (not a copy) of the object. Callers would be allowed to change `foo`'s state (locally) and changes would go unnoticed. Components wouldn't be aware of the changes, leading to absolute indeterminism. We wouldn't know when or why the `bar` changed. That's inherent in any public unsafe global state and a concern for any good developer.

OP's snippet might not suffer from these issues, since `bar` is a mere string printed in a meaningless template, but I know global states like this are rarely a string whose only purpose is to be printed somewhere and nothing else. You can do that by storing and fetching the string in/from the localStorage, which is a way simpler solution and no framework dependency is required.

That said, I find attaching components to `Observable` a more rounded solution because it gives me a sense of control. I can handle when changes happen and what to do with them. That's quite important If I pretend to work with the global state and Angular components' life cycle.

It also allows me to decouple child components from the service. Basically, the parent asks the service for an observable and passes this one to the child component as `@Input`. That makes the child component agnostic to the source of the changes at the same time that allows it to be aware of them. Every component within the hierarchy creates the subscription and callback. That makes for a good encapsulation.

The main issue of this approach is the subscription. Observables are not tax-free. There's a loop checking out things. But the solution is quite simple since Angular provides us with an `OnDestroy` hook which is a perfect place to cast `subscription.unsubscribe()`.